# php/sql code to display pivot data

Tags: php, mysql

Tablename - Receipt table

coupondate  - varchar

Data present in table like below.

```
coupondate    customer      
02-04-2015     A         
02-05-2015     A         
02-06-2015     A         
02-07-2015     A        
02-08-2015     A       
02-09-2015     A  

05-04-2015     B         
05-05-2015     B         
05-06-2015     B         
05-07-2015     B        
05-08-2015     B       
05-09-2015     B
```

In above table student A present from 02-04-2015 upto 02-09-2015 so i need to display p on student  A from 02-04 upto 02-09.

In above table student B present from 05-04-2015 upto 05-09-2015 so i need to display p on student  B from 05-04 upto 05-09 like wise...

**Expected output**

```
  Customer 02-04 03-04 04-04 05-04 06-04 07-04 08-04 09-04 10-04 11-04 12-04 13-04 14-04 -15-04.....like wise upto 02-09
     A       P     P     P     P     P      P     P    P    P     P      P    .......like wise upto 15-09   
     B                         P      P      P     P    P    P     P      like wise....upto 05-09
```

But the main thing this is present and absent report...

And i need to fetch all data using query..bcoz Certain where condition also in my query..

**for ex**  if i fetch data from 02-04-2015 to 05-04-2015 so this display records upto only 3 days filtered date...

below is my sql query to fetch data from db

```
SELECT RE.*, DATEDIFF(MAX(STR_TO_DATE(RE.coupondate, '%d-%m-%Y')), MIN(STR_TO_DATE(RE.coupondate, '%d-%m-%Y'))) AS totaldiff
                 FROM receipt_entry RE LEFT JOIN city_master CM ON RE.city_name = CM.id WHERE CM.cityname = :cityname AND str_to_date(RE.coupondate,'%d-%m-%Y') 
                 BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate GROUP BY RE.receipt_no
```

**below code is used to display days in header..**

```
<?php
$startdate = $_POST['fromdate'];
$enddate = $_POST['todate'];
$start = date('d', strtotime($startdate));
$end=date('d', strtotime($enddate));
?>  

<?php   for ($x = $start; $x <= $end; $x++) { ?>
    <th width="58%"><?php echo $x; ?></th>
    <?php } ?>
```

**below code is used to display pivot data but not getting my expected output**

```
<?php  if (is_array($data)) { foreach($data as $row)    {   ?>
<tbody>
    <tr>                    
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['customer_name']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['startingdate']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['coupondate']); ?></td>

        <?php for ($x = $start; $x <= $end; $x++) { ?>  

        <?php if($row['coupondate'] == $x) { ?>

        <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $row['totaldiff']; $i++)
        {
        ?>
        <td>1</td>  
        <?php } ?>  

        <?php }  else { ?>
        <td>-</td>
        <?php } ?>      

        <?php } ?>

    </tr>
    <?php } }?>
</tbody>        
</table>
```

Comment: take array concept..explaining it how..store database values in array. store database date in another array to be name for td. if the td name will be matched with the first array element print the value A/P in that td...draw concept on paper first..this will be surely done by array & loop

Comment: I don't understand how the data set corresponds with the result set.

Comment: plz help me i tried more example but can not able to get output...plz help me with code....